# Mananging upload of images to create custom pdfs on heroku - right tools

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

Im desiging an app which allows users to upload images (max 500k per image, roughly 20 images) from their hard drive to the site so as to be able to make some custom boardgames (e.g. snakes and ladders) in pdf formate. These will be created with prawn instantly and then made available for instant download.

Neither the images uploaded nor the pdfs created need to be saved on my apps side permanently. The moment the user downloads the pdf they are no longer needed.

Heroku doesn't support saving files to the system (it does allow to the tmp directory but says you shouldnt rely on it striking it out for me). I'm wondering what tools / services I should be looking into to get round this. Ive looked into paperclip, I'm wondering if this is right for this type of job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paperclip is on the right track, but the key insight is you need to use the S3 storage backend (Paperclip uses the FS by default which as you've noticed is no good on Heroku). It's pretty handy; instead of flushing writes out to the file system, it uses the AWS::S3 gem to upload them to S3. You can read more about it in the rdoc here: http://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/blob/master/lib/paperclip/storage/s3.rb

Here's how the flow would work:

I'd let your users upload their multiple source images. Here's an article on allowing multiple attachments to one model with paperclip: http://www.cordinc.com/blog/2009/04/multiple-attachments-with-vali.html.

Then when you're ready to generate the PDF (probably in a background job, right?), what you do is download all the source images to somewhere in tmp/ (make sure the directory is based on your model id or something so if two people do this at once, the files don't get stepped on). Once you've got all the images downloaded, you can generate your PDF. I know this is using the file system, but as long as you do all your filesystem interactions in one request or job cycle, it will work, your files will still be there. I use this method in a couple production web apps. You can't count on tmp/ being there between requests, but within one it's reliably there.

Storing your generated PDF on S3 with paperclip makes sense too, since then you can just hand your users the S3 URL. If you want you can make something to clear the files off every so often if you don't want to pay the S3 costs, but they should be trivial.

Comment: thanks for the info its come in very handy. Already nearly implemented it

Answer (score 1):

`Paperclip` sounds like an ideal candidate. It will save images in  `RAILS_ROOT/public/system/`, which is both persistent and private (shouldn't be able to be enumerated on shared hosting).

You can configure it to produce thumbnails of your images if you wish.

And it can remove the images it manages when the associated model is destroyed - after your user downloads their PDF, and you delete the record from the database.

`Prawn` might not be appropriate, depending on the complexity of the PDFs you need to generate. If you have $$$, go for `PrinceXML` and the `princely` gem. I've had some success with `wkhtmltopdf`, which generates PDFs from a `Webkit` render of HTML/CSS - but it doesn't support any of the advanced page manipulation stuff that `Prince` does.

Comment: thanks for the paperclip suggestion. I cant save to the system though as heroku doesnt support that.